# why is this happening, How do I correct this "mistake"?

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DksIU.png)

And also when I try to start in the same code the application on the phone stops responding I think the error would be in some code of the connection but I'm not sure because I'm very noob in this question

And another question, is my connection correct?

```
public class ConexaoClass {

String classs = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd_tela";
String un = "admin";
String pass = "96960409w";


@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public Connection CONN(){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    Connection conn = null;
    String connURL = null;
    try{
        Class.forName(classs);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, un, pass);

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return conn;
}
```

Comment: Why is **what** happening? Do you understand why this is a *very poor* question title?

Comment: It looks like `Login` is declared as a local class, after where you use it. Move its declaration before the usage (and/or make it a non-local class, because local classes are pretty unusual).

Comment: Could edit your question to put a more specific title? And describe the error/wrong behaviour as text in the question? People can't always access uploaded images

Answer (score 1):

Simplifying your code:

```
class Login {}  // Can't see this, but I know it's around somewhere. Maybe imported.

void someMethod() {
  Login login = new Login();
  login.execute();

  class Login { 
    void execute() {}
  }
}
```

The `Login` with the `execute()` method is a [*local* class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html), declared after where you use it. Local classes are only in scope *after* their declaration. [Language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.3):

> The scope of a local class declaration immediately enclosed by a block (§14.2) is the rest of the immediately enclosing block, including its own class declaration.

so your `Login` is actually referring to the class defined outside the method, which doesn't have an `execute()` method, meaning the `execute()` symbol can't be found.

Move the local declaration before:

```
class Login() {}

void someMethod() {
  class Login { 
    void execute() {}
  }

  Login login = new Login();
  login.execute();
}
```

But really, local classes aren't very widely used, and it's confusing to have a local class which hides another class.

Consider renaming it.